# Migrating from Firestore to Mongodb Realm in React Native, working with Phone Auth and Change Streams

Tags: mongodb, firebase, react-native, realm, changestream

I'm trying to utilize MongoDB Change Streams in a way that mimics listeners in Firebase. I've read that Change Streams are not akin to typical pub/sub behavior, but I'm curious about how to set it up properly in a way that stays compliant with Mongodb Realm and also fulfills my use case. A few things about my app:

1. I'm using Firebase Phone Auth as the main authentication provider. But I'm migrating the backend to MongoDB Realm because Firestore doesn't fulfill some database needs I have. I'm able to log in with Custom JWT credentials for log in, but in the `auth().onAuthStateChanged` function within my App.js, do I need to log the user into Realm as well? For example, if I have a user in my production app who is already logged in, I want them to be authenticated into Realm without having to log in again once I make the change. Code:

```
const jwt = await auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
const credentials = Realm.Credentials.jwt(jwt);
const realmUser = await app.logIn(credentials);
console.log("realm user is ", realmUser.id); //this prints an id
console.log("current user in app is", app.currentUser); //sometimes this is an empty object {}
```

I suppose I could check if app.currentUser exists in onAuthStateChanged. If not, then they are either logged out or haven't used the app since the migration. In which case I can log the user into Realm and they'll be able to connect to the backend.

2. When the user is using my app, I want to set up a listener on their specific document to listen for updates. I am putting opening a changeStream in the `componentDidMount` method to listen for updates. Based on a certain update, I plan on changing the UI of the screen. Here's the code I have and I was able to get it working:

```
    const mongodb = app.currentUser.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas");
    
    const single = mongodb.db("db-name").collection("collection-name");
    try {
      for (const change of single.watch({
        filter: {
          operationType: "update",
          "fullDocument.userId": "some-user-id",
        },
      })) {
        // The change event will always represent a newly inserted perennial
        
        const { documentKey, fullDocument } = change;
        console.log(`new document: ${documentKey}`, fullDocument);
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

So I open the stream while my user is using my app and listen for updates. When the user backgrounds my app, does Mongodb close the change stream automatically? I'm opening this change stream in React Native on the client side itself, and there isn't a `close()` function that is available to me.

I've also read through these docs and wasn't able to find anything.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/mongodb/watch-documents/
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/query-mongodb/#std-label-react-native-mongodb-watch-a-collection

I know there's a lot on here so thanks in advance for any insight. I'm doing the migration myself and just stuck on these two concepts. After this, it should be smooth sailing!

Comment: Realm offers authentication. IMO, it's not as robust as the Firebase implementation, it will suit most needs. *do I need to log the user into Realm as well* - well, that depends. Yes? Maybe? If you want security and user configured data then yes. It's going to be really hard to tell without understanding the entire use case. Realm has it's own observer pattern so why implement changestream as well? This question is going to be too broad to be addressed here on SO.

Comment: @Sishir Mohan were you able to figure it out?